# Php storm does not notice on missing fields

Tags: phpstorm

I did not get any notice when my fields in class are missing , please see example

```
class test
{
    public function abc()
    {
        $this->variable = "abc";
    }

}
```

in here phpstorm must show me notice for $this->variable , because it's does not created as field in this class.
Any advice?

Comment: And what `class test()` supposed to mean? Did you checked your code example before posting?

Comment: Please show a screenshot of how it looks for you in Default editor color scheme (preferable). It works just fine for me: http://postimg.org/image/mb27tmlhp/ -- as you can see it gives me a low priority notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your Inspection profile is checked for `Undefined Fields`?

[image]